# Unhandled rejection TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of null

Tags: node.js

Following is my code:

```
router.post('/getTrainingProgramByTPType', function (req, res) {
    var query = { ... }; // simplified for clarity in stackoverflow

    models.TrainingProgram.findAll(query).then(function (trainingPrograms) {
        var resData = [];
        console.log(typeof req.body.userType, req.body.userType);

        trainingPrograms.forEach(trainingProgram => {
            if (trainingProgram.CourseType.name === req.body.userType || trainingProgram.CourseType.name === "EVERYONE" || (!req.body.isExperienced && trainingProgram.CourseType.name === "OPTIONAL")) {
                resData.push(trainingProgram);
            }
            else {
                var resDataCourse = [];
                var a;
                trainingProgram.Courses.forEach(course => {
                    course.Classes.forEach(classes => {
                        classes.ClassRecords.forEach(classRecord => {
                            if (classRecord.User.email === req.body.email) {
                                a = 1;
                                resDataCourse.push(course);
                            }
                        });
                    });
                });

                if (a === 1) {
                    resData.push({
                        id: trainingProgram.id,
                        name: trainingProgram.name,
                        description: trainingProgram.description,
                        imgLink: trainingProgram.imgLink,
                        courseTypeId: trainingProgram.courseTypeId,
                        CourseType: trainingProgram.CourseType,
                        Courses: resDataCourse
                    });
                }
            }
        });

        var datasend = {
            success: true,
            msg: 'send list success',
            trainingProgram: resData,
        };
        res.send(datasend);
    });
});
```

And I'm getting this error:

> ```
> at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (C:\Users\huy.q.lam\Desktop\master\DEK-Talentnet\DCC\node_modules\sequelize\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:522:17)
> at Promise._settlePromise (C:\Users\huy.q.lam\Desktop\master\DEK-Talentnet\DCC\node_modules\sequelize\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:567:18)
> at Promise._settlePromise0 (C:\Users\huy.q.lam\Desktop\master\DEK-Talentnet\DCC\node_modules\sequelize\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:612:10)
> at Promise._settlePromises (C:\Users\huy.q.lam\Desktop\master\DEK-Talentnet\DCC\node_modules\sequelize\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:691:18)
> at Promise._fulfill (C:\Users\huy.q.lam\Desktop\master\DEK-Talentnet\DCC\node_modules\sequelize\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:636:18)
> at MappingPromiseArray.PromiseArray._resolve (C:\Users\huy.q.lam\Desktop\master\DEK-Talentnet\DCC\node_modules\sequelize\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise_array.js:125:1 9)
> at MappingPromiseArray._promiseFulfilled (C:\Users\huy.q.lam\Desktop\master\DEK-Talentnet\DCC\node_modules\sequelize\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\map.js:101:18)
> at Promise._settlePromise (C:\Users\huy.q.lam\Desktop\master\DEK-Talentnet\DCC\node_modules\sequelize\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:572:26)
> at Promise._settlePromise0 (C:\Users\huy.q.lam\Desktop\master\DEK-Talentnet\DCC\node_modules\sequelize\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:612:10)
> at Promise._settlePromises (C:\Users\huy.q.lam\Desktop\master\DEK-Talentnet\DCC\node_modules\sequelize\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:691:18)
> at Promise._fulfill (C:\Users\huy.q.lam\Desktop\master\DEK-Talentnet\DCC\node_modules\sequelize\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:636:18)
> at Promise._resolveCallback (C:\Users\huy.q.lam\Desktop\master\DEK-Talentnet\DCC\node_modules\sequelize\node_modules\bluebird\js\release\promise.js:431:57)
> ```

What might be causing the TypeError?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I bet that `trainingProgram.CourseType` is null. In this case, when you try to access `trainingProgram.CourseType.name`, you get an `Error`:

```
trainingPrograms.forEach(trainingProgram => {
    if (trainingProgram.CourseType.name === ...) { // <- ERROR HERE
        ....
    }
    ...
}
```

I don't understand your app logic, but you could try to protect your condition against that case, for example:

```
if (trainingProgram.CourseType && trainingProgram.CourseType.name === ...) {
```